# How to hide rows if result is false (Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase

Currently, my the result store in my firebase is true or false and I want to display the user output only if the result is true.

```
<html>
<tr *ngFor="let content of user">
                <td>{{content.fullname}}</td>
                <td>{{content.createdIndividualAt | date}}</td>
                <td>{{getMember(content.hasMembership)}}</td>
            </tr>
</html>



constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
private individualSrv: IndividualService,
) {
let res = individualSrv.getAll();
res.then(result => {
  result.subscribe(async _user => {
    this.user = _user;
  });
});

   getMember(hasMembership: boolean): string {
if(hasMembership == true) {
  return 'Is member'; }
else {
  return ''
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't break the tr/td structure adding other elements, you can have a cleaner and more consistent output just using `ng-container`:

```
<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let content of user">
             <tr *ngIf="content.hasMembership">
                    <td >{{content.fullname}}</td>
                    <td>{{content.createdIndividualAt | date}}</td>
                    <td>{{getMember(content.hasMembership)}}</td>
             </tr>
     </ng-container>
</table>
```

Ps: Don't add html tags in your component, and don't use `async` if you don't await anything!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following changes, use ngIf for show and hide viceversa

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let content of user">
            <span *ngIf="content.hasMembership">
                <td >{{content.fullname}}</td>
                <td>{{content.createdIndividualAt | date}}</td>
                <td>{{getMember(content.hasMembership)}}</td>
            </span>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</html>
```

Comment: Better to do it with ng-container. Else you are injecting useless elements in the DOM